# Alerts that do not match labels

Tags: label, pine-script, alert, pine-script-v5

The following part of the PineScript code generates the four types of alerts but not always the corresponding labels:

```
long_filter := (score_long >= score_filter)
short_filter := (score_short >= score_filter)

show_long := long_filter
show_short := short_filter

long_color := color.new(#006400, 0)
short_color := color.new(#800000, 0)

if long_filter
    long_label := label.new(x= bar_index, y= low, text= strong_long_label, style= label.style_label_up, color= long_color, textcolor= color.white, tooltip= show_details ? long_tooltip: na, size= size.normal, yloc= yloc.belowbar)
    alert("Pair: " + syminfo.ticker + "\nDirection: LONG" + "\nTimeframe: " + str.tostring(timeframe.period) + "\nEntry: " + str.tostring(close), alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
if short_filter
    short_label := label.new(x= bar_index, y= high, text= strong_short_label, style= label.style_label_down, color= short_color, textcolor= color.white, tooltip= show_details ? short_tooltip: na, size= size.normal, yloc= yloc.abovebar)
    alert("Pair: " + syminfo.ticker + "\nDirection: SHORT" + "\nTimeframe: " + str.tostring(timeframe.period) + "\nEntry: " + str.tostring(close), alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

alertcondition(long_filter, title="LONG", message="Pair: {{ticker}}\nDirection: LONG\nTimeframe: {{interval}}\nEntry: {{close}}")
alertcondition(short_filter, title="SHORT", message="Pair: {{ticker}}\nDirection: SHORT\nTimeframe: {{interval}}\nEntry: {{close}}")
```

Could you help me understand why the same conditions don't work the same for alerts and labels?